# Paperclip processor not changing file contents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am trying to convert the lines of an uploaded text file attachment using a Paperclip processor in rails.  I can verify with a debugger that my processor is called, but the file that gets attached is my original file, not the file written by the processor.  Here is my processor:

```
module Paperclip
  class Utf8 < Processor
    def initialize(file, options={}, attachment=nil)
      super
      @file           = file
      @attachment     = attachment
      @current_format = File.extname(@file.path)
      @format         = options[:format]
      @basename       = File.basename(@file.path, @current_format)
    end

    def make
      @file.rewind
      tmp = Tempfile.new([@basename, @format])

      IO.foreach(@file.path) do |line|
        tmp << line.encode('UTF-8', 'binary', invalid: :replace, undef: :replace, replace: '')
      end

      tmp.flush
      tmp
    end
  end
end
```

and here is my model:

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :file,
                    storage: :s3,
                    s3_credentials: Rails.root.join('config', 'aws.yml'),
                    bucket: Rails.application.config.s3_bucket,
                    processors: [:utf8],
                    styles: {
                        utf8: {
                            format: 'txt'
                        }
                    }
end
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?  As I understand it, the file returned from make is what paperclip attaches to the model.  Might s3 have anything to do with this?

Comment: Maybe this is not your case, but what paperclip generally does is store the original filename in the database and depending on the transformations you define, stores different versions on the filesystem. The original plus the transformations.

So, what you get as an attachment much depends on how you send it to the browser. In your case you probably need to tell your controller how to send your file.

Comment: Ah, I see that now.  Each processor saves a new version of the file.  How would I have the controller send different styles?

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution: paperclip saves each style is as a separate file.  To overwrite the original file instead of creating a new one, I had to change my model to:

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :file,
                    storage: :s3,
                    s3_credentials: Rails.root.join('config', 'aws.yml'),
                    bucket: Rails.application.config.s3_bucket,
                    processors: [:utf8],
                    styles: {
                        original: { # specifying original style here causes the original file to be overwritten
                            format: 'txt'
                        }
                    }
end
```